# .htaccess simple redirection and too many rediercections: how to solve that?

Tags: .htaccess

my site (domain.com) is now located into /var/www/
and you can also access it directly through its IP: 88.88.88.88

I would like to obtain:
when user enter the IP : 88.88.88.88, it redirects to 88.88.88.88/reboot/

if user enters the full domain name, it shows the site as it does now.

I tried with .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} 88.88.88.88
RewriteRule .* http://88.88.88.88/reboot/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com
RewriteRule .* http://www.mysite.com [R=301,L]
```

**does not work good:**

www.mysite.com :GOOD

mysite.com: GOOD

88.88.88.88 ->redirects to 88.88.88.88/reboot : GOOD

**but then it generates an error: Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)**

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're on **88.88.88.88/reboot**, your HTTP_HOST is still equal to *88.88.88.88*.

Try adding a RewriteCond rule depending on the REQUEST_URI, which will redirect everything that is not `/reboot` to `/reboot` :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} 88.88.88.88
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/reboot/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://88.88.88.88/reboot/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com
RewriteRule .* http://www.mysite.com [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` comes because your rule loops.
Whenever a request comes to host 88.88.88.88 , you redirect it to 88.88.88.88/reboot/ , but /reboot/ uri is also on that host, so it redirects again and loops.

If you only want to redirect / to /reboot/ on host 88.88.88.88 , you need to alter your `RewriteRule` to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} 88.88.88.88
RewriteRule ^/$ http://88.88.88.88/reboot/ [R=301,L]
```

If, however, you wish to redirect everything outside of /reboot/ , then you need to add a condition (`RewriteCond`):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} 88.88.88.88
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/reboot/
RewriteRule ^/$ http://88.88.88.88/reboot/ [R=301,L]
```

(keep the rest of the rules intact).